# Topology : R open domain and closed domain

Tags: general-topology

I dont understand why we can consider the domain R and $\varnothing$ as close and open domains ?

I have no idea of how to demonstrates it and like to see how to do it?

Edit : My definition : an open space is circle where each point contained can be circled by a circle with a very small diameter and all the points contained in this small circle are contained in the big one. A closed ones doesn't have this property because on the border of the circle we can't trace this small circle such as all points contained inside are contained in the set.

Comment: How are you defining open and closed? In general, it is *assumed* both the space and the empty set are clopen. On the other hand in a metric space, one may define a set to be open based on the metric.

Comment: @user1 an open space is circle where each point contained can be circled by a circle with a very small diameter and all the points contained in this small circle are contained in the big one. A closed ones doesn't have this property because on the border of the circle we can't trace this small circle such as all points contained inside are contained in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is not a correct one. There are plenty of open sets that are not a circle.

Let's use the definition that you may have in your mind: a set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is ***open*** if for any $x \in U$ there is a circle without the boundary $B$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$.

We answer if $\emptyset$ is open. If $x \in \emptyset$, then by vacuous truth, there exists a circle $B$ without a boundary such that $x \in B \subseteq \emptyset$, so $\emptyset$ must be open.

I think it is pictorially clear that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open, using our definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in a general topology since by defintion:

If $X$ is a set  then a family of subset $\tau=(\mathcal O_i) $  of $X$ is called a topology on $X$ if:

- **Both the empty set and $X$ are elements of $\tau$**
- Any union of elements of τ is an element of $\tau$
- Any intersection of finitely many elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$

The elements $\mathcal O_i$ of $\tau$ are called **open** subset of $X$ and their **complements** are called **closed** subset.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you gave does not seem to be accurate. You can define openness however you like, up to a [point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Mathematical_definition). From the linked definition of a topology, it is clear that your definition fails to define a topology as the intersection of two circles may not be a circle.

The usual definition of **open set** in a metric space, like $\mathbb R^2$, is that $U\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is open if and only if for every point $x\in U$ there is an open ball (circle without boundary) contained in $U$ centered at $x$. It is straight-forward to check that this defines a topology. In particular, we see that $\emptyset$ is open vacuously and $\mathbb R^2$ is open since one can construct, say, the circle of radius $1$ around any point $x$.

Additionally, one defines a set to be **closed** if it is the complement of an open set. So, the empty set is closed since it is the complement of the space $\mathbb R^2$ and similarly $\mathbb R^2$ is closed since it is the complement of the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if we want open sets to obey standard properties:

1. The intersection of open sets is open
2. The union of finitely many open sets is open

and if we want the complement of an open set to be closed, then it makes a lot of sense to define the empty set and the entire space $X$ as open.  (1) implies that $\varnothing$ is open as long as there exist two disjoint sets in your space, and (2) implies that $X$ as open as long as every point is a member of some open set.  Since $X$ and $\varnothing$ are complements, it follows that both are  closed well.

Perhaps even more telling, suppose we have some space $X$ in which the empty set and/or the entire set is *not* open, and which obeys (1) and (2).  Then define $Y$ to be the same space, with the only difference that $\varnothing$ and $Y$ itself are now open.  You can check that $Y$ *still* satisfies both (1) and (2).  It is thus taken as an axiom that $X$ and $\varnothing$ are open from the start, because at the very least, *it can't hurt* to do so.

In fact the axioms of a topological space are exactly (1), (2), and the assumption that $X$ and $\varnothing$ are open.